# Using XSLT to transform modified Dublin Core XML

Tags: xml, xslt, marc

I want to transform custom xml that has been tagged with unique identifiers into MARCXML, but I have no idea where to start. For example, I need to take `<untl:title qualifier="officialtitle" >Equation of State and Heat Content of Uranium</untl:title>` and assign it to a 245 field. Here is my attempt at pulling the title, but I do not know where to specify which qualifier to use to pull from the correct element. My understanding of XSLT is very sparse and any help is greatly apreciated.

`<xsl:for-each select="untl:title">`
`<datafield tag="245" ind1="1" ind2="0">`
`<subfield code="a">`
 `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`
`</subfield>`
`</datafield>`
`</xsl:for-each>`

Edit(8/17/2020):I'm using a program called MarcEdit and he has created presets of XSLT sheets that I believe can be modified for UNTL, however I don't have the knowledge or expertise currently to customize them. You'll see the target structure sheet, my current code, and the preset XSLT I'm using as a reference below.

Code so Far: Not alot, really trying to nail down Namespaces for the UNTL. From reading online, my understanding  of the xsl:import is that it will allow the target stucture (MARC21slimUtils) to be imported into my current XSL file?.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:untl="https://library.unt.edu/digital-projects-unit/metadata/input-guidelines-descriptive/"
    xmlns:untlterms ="https://library.unt.edu/digital-projects-unit/metadata/input-guidelines-descriptive/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://digital2.library.unt.edu/untl.xsd"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"  exclude-result-prefixes=" untl untlterms ">
 
    <xsl:import href="MARC21slimUtils.xsl"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <collection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd" >
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </collection>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example Record:

```
<record>
  <header>
    <identifier>info:ark/67531/metadc714189</identifier>
    <datestamp>2019-04-23T20:54:10Z</datestamp>
    <setSpec>partner:UNTGD</setSpec>
    <setSpec>collection:TRAIL</setSpec>
    <setSpec>collection:TRAMC</setSpec>
    <setSpec>access_rights:public</setSpec>
  </header>
  <metadata>
    <untl:metadata xmlns:untl="http://digital2.library.unt.edu/untl/">
      <untl:title qualifier="officialtitle">Critical-Assembly Studies on an Intermediate Reactor for Aircraft Propulsion</untl:title>
      <untl:title qualifier="seriestitle">BMI (Series)</untl:title>
      <untl:title qualifier="seriestitle">Battelle Memorial Institute Reports</untl:title>
      <untl:title qualifier="addedtitle">Battelle Memorial Institute Report BMI-1209</untl:title>
      <untl:creator qualifier="aut">
        <untl:name>Marinaccio, Lawrence F.</untl:name>
        <untl:type>per</untl:type>
      </untl:creator>
      <untl:creator qualifier="aut">
        <untl:name>Jung, Richard G.</untl:name>
        <untl:type>per</untl:type>
      </untl:creator>
      <untl:creator qualifier="aut">
        <untl:name>Jankowski, Francis J.</untl:name>
        <untl:type>per</untl:type>
      </untl:creator>
      <untl:creator qualifier="aut">
        <untl:name>Dingee, David A.</untl:name>
        <untl:type>per</untl:type>
      </untl:creator>
      <untl:creator qualifier="aut">
        <untl:name>Chastain, Joel W.</untl:name>
        <untl:type>per</untl:type>
      </untl:creator>
      <untl:contributor qualifier="org">
        <untl:name>U.S. Atomic Energy Commission</untl:name>
        <untl:type>org</untl:type>
      </untl:contributor>
      <untl:contributor qualifier="org">
        <untl:name>Battelle Memorial Institute</untl:name>
        <untl:type>org</untl:type>
      </untl:contributor>
      <untl:publisher>
        <untl:location>Columbus, Ohio</untl:location>
        <untl:name>Battelle Memorial Institute</untl:name>
      </untl:publisher>
      <untl:date qualifier="creation">1957-07-15</untl:date>
      <untl:language>eng</untl:language>
      <untl:description qualifier="content">The following report studies an intermediate solid-fuel reactor system for aircraft propulsion.</untl:description>
      <untl:description qualifier="physical">[87] p. : ill., tables ; 28 cm.</untl:description>
      <untl:subject qualifier="LCSH">Airplanes -- Nuclear power plants.</untl:subject>
      <untl:subject qualifier="LCSH">Liquid metal cooled reactors.</untl:subject>
      <untl:primarySource>1</untl:primarySource>
      <untl:coverage qualifier="placeName">United States</untl:coverage>
      <untl:collection>TRAIL</untl:collection>
      <untl:collection>TRAMC</untl:collection>
      <untl:institution>UNTGD</untl:institution>
      <untl:rights qualifier="note">The contents of TRAIL Microcard Collection, hosted by the University of North Texas Libraries (digital content including images, text, and sound and video recordings) are made publicly available by the collection-holding partners for use in research, teaching, and private study. For the full terms of use, see https://digital.library.unt.edu/terms-of-use/</untl:rights>
      <untl:resourceType>text_report</untl:resourceType>
      <untl:format>text</untl:format>
      <untl:identifier qualifier="itemURL">https://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc714189/</untl:identifier>
      <untl:identifier qualifier="OCLC">922939295</untl:identifier>
      <untl:identifier qualifier="SUDOC">Y 3.AT 7:22/BMI-1209</untl:identifier>
      <untl:identifier qualifier="REP-NO">BMI-1209</untl:identifier>
      <untl:identifier qualifier="thumbnailURL">https://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc714189/small/</untl:identifier>
      <untl:identifier qualifier="ARK">ark:/67531/metadc714189</untl:identifier>
      <untl:identifier qualifier="iiif-manifest">https://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc714189/manifest/</untl:identifier>
      <untl:note qualifier="display">Digitized from microopaque cards.</untl:note>
      <untl:meta qualifier="system">DC</untl:meta>
      <untl:meta qualifier="ark">ark:/67531/metadc714189</untl:meta>
      <untl:meta qualifier="metadataCreationDate">2018-02-12, 07:42:45</untl:meta>
      <untl:meta qualifier="metadataModifier">htarver</untl:meta>
      <untl:meta qualifier="metadataModificationDate">2019-04-23, 20:54:10</untl:meta>
      <untl:meta qualifier="hidden">False</untl:meta>
    </untl:metadata>
  </metadata>
</record>
```

Target Structure (MARC21slimUtils):

```
xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.1" xml:lang="en">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation> MARCXML: The MARC 21 XML Schema Prepared by Corey Keith May 21, 2002 - Version 1.0 - Initial Release ********************************************** Changes. August 4, 2003 - Version 1.1 - Removed import of xml namespace and the use of xml:space="preserve" attributes on the leader and controlfields. Whitespace preservation in these subfields is accomplished by the use of xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve" May 21, 2009 - Version 1.2 - in subfieldcodeDataType the pattern "[\da-z!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?{}_^`~\[\]\\]{1}" changed to: "[\dA-Za-z!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?{}_^`~\[\]\\]{1}" i.e "A-Z" added after "[\d" before "a-z" to allow upper case. This change is for consistency with the documentation. ************************************************************ This schema supports XML markup of MARC21 records as specified in the MARC documentation (see www.loc.gov). It allows tags with alphabetics and subfield codes that are symbols, neither of which are as yet used in the MARC 21 communications formats, but are allowed by MARC 21 for local data. The schema accommodates all types of MARC 21 records: bibliographic, holdings, bibliographic with embedded holdings, authority, classification, and community information. </xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:element name="record" type="recordType" nillable="true" id="record.e">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>record is a top level container element for all of the field elements which compose the record</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="collection" type="collectionType" nillable="true" id="collection.e">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>collection is a top level container element for 0 or many records</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="collectionType" id="collection.ct">
<xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xsd:element ref="record"/>
</xsd:sequence>
<xsd:attribute name="id" type="idDataType" use="optional"/>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="recordType" id="record.ct">
<xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
<xsd:element name="leader" type="leaderFieldType"/>
<xsd:element name="controlfield" type="controlFieldType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
<xsd:element name="datafield" type="dataFieldType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xsd:sequence>
<xsd:attribute name="type" type="recordTypeType" use="optional"/>
<xsd:attribute name="id" type="idDataType" use="optional"/>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="recordTypeType" id="type.st">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:NMTOKEN">
<xsd:enumeration value="Bibliographic"/>
<xsd:enumeration value="Authority"/>
<xsd:enumeration value="Holdings"/>
<xsd:enumeration value="Classification"/>
<xsd:enumeration value="Community"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:complexType name="leaderFieldType" id="leader.ct">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>MARC21 Leader, 24 bytes</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:simpleContent>
<xsd:extension base="leaderDataType">
<xsd:attribute name="id" type="idDataType" use="optional"/>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="leaderDataType" id="leader.st">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
<xsd:pattern value="[\d ]{5}[\dA-Za-z ]{1}[\dA-Za-z]{1}[\dA-Za-z ]{3}(2| )(2| )[\d ]{5}[\dA-Za-z ]{3}(4500| )"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:complexType name="controlFieldType" id="controlfield.ct">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>MARC21 Fields 001-009</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:simpleContent>
<xsd:extension base="controlDataType">
<xsd:attribute name="id" type="idDataType" use="optional"/>
<xsd:attribute name="tag" type="controltagDataType" use="required"/>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="controlDataType" id="controlfield.st">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="controltagDataType" id="controltag.st">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
<xsd:pattern value="00[1-9A-Za-z]{1}"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:complexType name="dataFieldType" id="datafield.ct">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>MARC21 Variable Data Fields 010-999</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xsd:element name="subfield" type="subfieldatafieldType"/>
</xsd:sequence>
<xsd:attribute name="id" type="idDataType" use="optional"/>
<xsd:attribute name="tag" type="tagDataType" use="required"/>
<xsd:attribute name="ind1" type="indicatorDataType" use="required"/>
<xsd:attribute name="ind2" type="indicatorDataType" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="tagDataType" id="tag.st">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
<xsd:pattern value="(0([1-9A-Z][0-9A-Z])|0([1-9a-z][0-9a-z]))|(([1-9A-Z][0-9A-Z]{2})|([1-9a-z][0-9a-z]{2}))"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="indicatorDataType" id="ind.st">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
<xsd:pattern value="[\da-z ]{1}"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:complexType name="subfieldatafieldType" id="subfield.ct">
<xsd:simpleContent>
<xsd:extension base="subfieldDataType">
<xsd:attribute name="id" type="idDataType" use="optional"/>
<xsd:attribute name="code" type="subfieldcodeDataType" use="required"/>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="subfieldDataType" id="subfield.st">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="subfieldcodeDataType" id="code.st">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
<xsd:pattern value="[\dA-Za-z!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?{}_^`~\[\]\\]{1}"/>
<!--  "A-Z" added after "\d" May 21, 2009  -->
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="idDataType" id="id.st">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:ID"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Reference XSLT Sheet from MarcEdit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/1.1" 
    xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/
        http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"  exclude-result-prefixes="dc dcterms oai_dc">
 
    <xsl:import href="MARC21slimUtils.xsl"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
  
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <collection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd" >
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </collection>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="OAI-PMH">
             <xsl:for-each select = "ListRecords/record/metadata/oai_dc:dc">
                <xsl:apply-templates  />
             </xsl:for-each>
             <xsl:for-each select = "GetRecord/record/metadata/oai_dc:dc">
                <xsl:apply-templates  />
             </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />
    <xsl:template match="oai_dc:dc">
        <record>
            <xsl:element name="leader">
                <xsl:variable name="type" select="dc:type"/>
                <xsl:variable name="leader06">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$type='collection'">p</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$type='dataset'">m</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$type='event'">r</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$type='image'">k</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$type='interactive resource'">m</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$type='service'">m</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$type='software'">m</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$type='sound'">i</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$type='text'">a</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>a</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="leader07">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$type='collection'">c</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>m</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('      ',$leader06,$leader07,' a       3u     ')"/>
            </xsl:element>

            <datafield tag="042" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
                <subfield code="a">dc</subfield>
            </datafield>


            
            <xsl:for-each select="dc:creator">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="(.!='') and (position()=1)">
                        <xsl:call-template name="persname_template">
                            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="." />
                            <xsl:with-param name="field" select="'100'" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="ind1" select = "'1'" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="ind2" select = "'0'" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'author'" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:if test=".!=''">
                            <xsl:call-template name="persname_template">
                                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="." />
                                <xsl:with-param name="field" select="'700'" />
                                <xsl:with-param name="ind1" select = "'1'" />
                                <xsl:with-param name="ind2" select = "'0'" />
                                <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'author'" />
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
            
        
            <xsl:for-each select="dc:title[1]">
                <datafield tag="245" ind1="0" ind2="0">
                    <subfield code="a">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </subfield>
                </datafield>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:for-each select="dc:title[position()>1]">
                <xsl:if test=".!=''">
                    <datafield tag="246" ind1="3" ind2="3">
                        <subfield code="a">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </subfield>
                    </datafield>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="dc:publisher">
                    <xsl:if test="translate(dc:publisher/.,'.,:;','')!=''">
                        <datafield tag="260" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="dc:date">   
                                <subfield code="b"><xsl:value-of select="dc:publisher[1]"/>, </subfield>    
                                <xsl:if test="translate(dc:date[1]/., '.,:;','')!=''">
                                    <subfield code="c"><xsl:value-of select="dc:date[1]" />.</subfield>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <subfield code="b"><xsl:value-of select="dc:publisher[1]"/>.</subfield> 
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        </datafield>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:if test="translate(dc:date[1],'.,:;','')!=''">
                        <datafield tag="260" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
                            <subfield code="c"><xsl:value-of select="dc:date[1]" />.</subfield>
                        </datafield>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:for-each select="dc:coverage">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="translate(., '0123456789-.?','')=''">
                        <!--Likely;this is a date-->
                        <datafield tag="500" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
                            <subfield code="a"><xsl:value-of select="."/></subfield>
                        </datafield>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <!--likely a geographic subject, we will print this later-->
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:for-each select="dc:identifier">
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <datafield tag="500" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
                        <subfield code="a"><xsl:value-of select="." /></subfield>
                    </datafield>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            
            <xsl:for-each select="dc:description">
                <datafield tag="520" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
                    <subfield code="a">
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                    </subfield>
                </datafield>
            </xsl:for-each>


            <xsl:for-each select="dc:rights">
                <datafield tag="540" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
                    <subfield code="a">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </subfield>
                </datafield>
            </xsl:for-each>


            <xsl:for-each select="dc:language">
                <datafield tag="546" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
                    <subfield code="a">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </subfield>
                </datafield>
            </xsl:for-each>



            <xsl:for-each select="dc:subject">
                <datafield tag="690" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
                    <subfield code="a">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </subfield>
                </datafield>
            </xsl:for-each>
            
            <xsl:for-each select="dc:coverage">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="translate(., '0123456789-.?','')=''">
                        <!--Likely; this is a date-->
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <!--likely a geographic subject-->
                        <datafield tag="691" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
                            <subfield code="a"><xsl:value-of select="." /></subfield>
                        </datafield>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
                                                                                            

            <xsl:for-each select="dc:type">
                <datafield tag="655" ind1="7" ind2=" ">
                    <subfield code="a">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </subfield>
                    <subfield code="2">local</subfield>
                </datafield>
            </xsl:for-each>

            

            <xsl:for-each select="dc:contributor">
                    <xsl:call-template name="persname_template">
                        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="." />
                        <xsl:with-param name="field" select="'100'" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="ind1" select = "'1'" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="ind2" select = "'0'" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'contributor'" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
            
            <xsl:for-each select="dc:source">
                <datafield tag="786" ind1="0" ind2=" ">
                    <subfield code="n">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </subfield>
                </datafield>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:for-each select="dc:relation">
                <datafield tag="787" ind1="0" ind2=" ">
                    <subfield code="n">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </subfield>
                </datafield>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:if test="dc:identifier">
                <datafield tag="856" ind1="4" ind2="1">
                    <subfield code="u"><xsl:value-of select="dc:identifier[last()]" /></subfield>
                    <subfield code="z">Connect to this object online.</subfield>
                </datafield>
            </xsl:if>
        </record>       

    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="persname_template">
      <xsl:param name="string" />
      <xsl:param name="field" />
      <xsl:param name="ind1" />
      <xsl:param name="ind2" />
      <xsl:param name="type" />
      <datafield>
         <xsl:attribute name="tag">
            <xsl:value-of select="$field" />
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:attribute name="ind1">
            <xsl:value-of select="$ind1" />
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:attribute name="ind2">
            <xsl:value-of select="$ind2" />
         </xsl:attribute>

         <!-- Sample input: Brightman, Samuel C. (Samuel Charles), 1911-1992 -->
         <!-- Sample output: $aBrightman, Samuel C. $q(Samuel Charles), $d1911-. -->
         <!-- will handle names with dashes e.g. Bourke-White, Margaret -->

         <!-- CAPTURE PRIMARY NAME BY LOOKING FOR A PAREN OR A DASH OR NEITHER -->
         <xsl:choose>
            <!-- IF A PAREN, STOP AT AN OPENING PAREN -->
            <xsl:when test="contains($string, '(')!=0">
               <subfield code="a">
                  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, '(')" />
               </subfield>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- IF A DASH, CHECK IF IT'S A DATE OR PART OF THE NAME -->
            <xsl:when test="contains($string, '-')!=0">
               <xsl:variable name="name_1" select="substring-before($string, '-')" />
               <xsl:choose>
                  <!-- IF IT'S A DATE REMOVE IT -->
                  <xsl:when test="translate(substring($name_1, (string-length($name_1)), 1), '0123456789', '9999999999') = '9'">
                     <xsl:variable name="name" select="substring($name_1, 1, (string-length($name_1)-6))" />
                     <subfield code="a">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$name" />
                     </subfield>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <!-- IF IT'S NOT A DATE, CHECK WHETHER THERE IS A DATE LATER -->
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                     <xsl:variable name="remainder" select="substring-after($string, '-')" />
                     <xsl:choose>
                        <!-- IF THERE'S A DASH, ASSUME IT'S A DATE AND REMOVE IT -->
                        <xsl:when test="contains($remainder, '-')!=0">
                           <xsl:variable name="tmp" select="substring-before($remainder, '-')" />
                           <xsl:variable name="name_2" select="substring($tmp, 1, (string-length($tmp)-6))" />
                           <subfield code="a">
                              <xsl:value-of select="$name_1" />-<xsl:value-of select="$name_2" />
                           </subfield>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <!-- IF THERE'S NO DASH IN THE REMAINDER, OUTPUT IT -->
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                           <subfield code="a">
                              <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
                           </subfield>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                     </xsl:choose>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- NO DASHES, NO PARENS, JUST OUTPUT THE NAME -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <subfield code="a">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
               </subfield>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>

         <!-- CAPTURE SECONDARY NAME IN PARENS FOR SUBFIELD Q -->
         <xsl:if test="contains($string, '(')!=0">
            <xsl:variable name="subq_tmp" select="substring-after($string, '(')" />
            <xsl:variable name="subq" select="substring-before($subq_tmp, ')')" />
            <subfield code="q">
               (<xsl:value-of select="$subq" />)
            </subfield>
         </xsl:if>

         <!-- CAPTURE DATE FOR SUBFIELD D, ASSUME DATE IS LAST ITEM IN FIELD -->
         <!-- Note: does not work if name has a dash in it -->
         <xsl:if test="contains($string, '-')!=0">
            <xsl:variable name="date_tmp" select="substring-before($string, '-')" />
            <xsl:variable name="remainder" select="substring-after($string, '-')" />
            <xsl:choose>
               <!-- CHECK SECOND HALF FOR ANOTHER DASH; IF PRESENT, ASSUME THAT IS DATE -->
               <xsl:when test="contains($remainder, '-')!=0">
                  <xsl:variable name="tmp" select="substring-before($remainder, '-')" />
                  <xsl:variable name="date_1" select="substring($remainder, (string-length($tmp)-3))" />
                  <!-- CHECK WHETHER IT HAS A NUMBER BEFORE IT AND IF SO, OUTPUT IT AS DATE -->
                  <xsl:if test="translate(substring($date_1, 1, 1), '0123456789', '9999999999') = '9'">
                     <subfield code="d">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$date_1" />.
                     </subfield>
                  </xsl:if>
               </xsl:when>
               <!-- OTHERWISE THIS IS THE ONLY DASH SO TAKE IT -->
               <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:variable name="date_2" select="substring($string, (string-length($date_tmp)-3))" />
                  <!-- CHECK WHETHER IT HAS A NUMBER BEFORE IT AND IF SO, OUTPUT IT AS DATE -->
                  <xsl:if test="translate(substring($date_2, 1, 1), '0123456789', '9999999999') = '9'">
                     <subfield code="d">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$date_2" />.
                     </subfield>
                  </xsl:if>
               </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:if>
         <subfield code="e"><xsl:value-of select="$type" /></subfield>
      </datafield>
   </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you include a target structure that you want to produce (or partial structure), and whatever xsl you have created so far?

Comment: @BrynLewis - I added more information on what I'm trying to do and the sheets that I'm referening below. I think with a better understanding I could edit the sheet from MarcEdit since UNTL seems to be a modified dublin core with more elements and attributes. However I lack the current knowledge to map out what exactly the sheet is doing outside of a basic level.

Comment: The MARC21 XML Schema is nice to know, but it would be much more helpful to see the desired result XML that belongs to your example record.

Comment: Also, please give the name and version of the XSLT processor you're using.

Comment: @Tomalak - After looking at the documentation, and reaching out the the creator, for MarcEdit, it looks like by defualt it uses MSXML, but has the option to use Saxon.NET. He gives a brief overview of the two,but it looks like MSXML is the more limited of the two.

Comment: @D.Larry That's true, but MSXML will do just fine for the use case, you can keep the default.

Comment: @Tomalak I was able to write out my code, but when I run it through the processeor, I end up with only this in the output file:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<collection xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd" xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />`

Comment: I've worked with your exact sample XML. If your actual data is different, all bets are off.

Comment: Your output looks like if ` <xsl:template match="/">` is the only one that runs. This would imply that your *actual* input does not have a `<record>` element at the top level, otherwise `<xsl:template match="record">` would run. Maybe it has `<record xmlns="...">` and you have dropped the namespace?

Comment: @Tomalak I just noticed that `<repository xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/"      xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`  was at the top. I removed that and I got more results. However it's just a block of empty tags besides author

Comment: @Tomalak I apologize. I just realized I made a critical mistake. I did not put any 
<xsl:value-of select> in my subfields. So of course it's not going to pull the data.

Comment: I guess you've learned not to make arbitrary modifications to your XML if your question is about that XML. I'm just at my phone right now, so I can't rewrite my answer. Try to understand what the current stylesheet does and how you would need to adapt it to your different XML structure. Maybe you can make some progress?

Comment: @Tomalak  I was able to figure out how to adjust stylesheet to accomadate the new XML structure and pull all the data I needed. Thank you for everything and answering all my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will get you started. It shows how to output field 100 (the author):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:untl="http://digital2.library.unt.edu/untl/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"
    exclude-result-prefixes="untl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <collection xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="record" />
        </collection>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="record">
        <record>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="metadata/untl:metadata" />
        </record>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="untl:metadata">
        <!-- add more <xsl:apply-templates> in the desired field output order -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="untl:creator[@qualifier='aut']" />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- write one template for each field -->
    <xsl:template match="untl:creator[@qualifier='aut']">
        <datafield tag="100" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">
                <xsl:value-of select="untl:name" />
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </subfield>
        </datafield>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've deliberately used one template per node, so you can see how the program flows from the root node of the input (`/`) and then continues to select specific nodes that each have their own templates.

I don't think you will need to include the `MARC21slimUtils.xsl` at all - I've looked at it and the utility functions in there add no real value in this case.

Output (aligned with the [official MARCXML sample](https://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/Sandburg/sandburg.xml)), formatted for readability:

```
<collection xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd"
>
  <record>
    <datafield tag="100" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">Marinaccio, Lawrence F.,</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="100" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">Jung, Richard G.,</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="100" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">Jankowski, Francis J.,</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="100" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">Dingee, David A.,</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="100" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">Chastain, Joel W.,</subfield>
    </datafield>
  </record>
</collection>
```

I'm not sure about the specifics, such as the trailing commas in the author's names, or the significance of `ind1` and `ind2`, you will understand these things better than I do.